# Java. Не могу записать строку в файл

Tags: java, строки

Здравствуйте, использую `FileWriter` для записи строки в файл. Файл создается и исключения не бросаются, но файл пустой. Я сначал конфигурирую строку (вывожу ее для проверки, все хорошо), а потом пишу эту строку в файл.

```
    File f = new File("database.txt");
    String s1 = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < place.size(); i++) {
        s1 = s1 + "\n" + place.get(i) + " "+ name.get(i) + " " + surname.get(i) + " ";
    }
    System.out.println(s1);
    try {
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(f);
        fileWriter.write(s1);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо в конце закрыть fileWriter: `fileWriter.close();`
Или по модному использовать `try with resource`, который закрывает автоматически

```
try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(f)) {
    fileWriter.write(s1);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("ERROR");
}
```

При закрытии автоматически выполняется операция `flush`, которая физически  записывает данные в файл.